# Constructor Definition in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

I am learning C++ for the first time, and I'm going through "Understanding the C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition, C++11". I'm having trouble getting some code to compile from an early section.

I'm creating a custom `Vector` class with some basic functionality using the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
    int size() { return sz; }
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};

double read_and_sum(int s) {
    Vector v(s);
    for (int i=0; i!=v.size(); ++i)
        std::cin>>v[i]; // read into elements

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i!=v.size(); ++i) 
        sum+=v[i]; // take the sum of the elements

    return sum; 
}

int main() {
    int sum = read_and_sum(5);
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

When I open the terminal and use g++ to compile the file, I get some errors in my `Vector` class:

```
vector2.cpp:5:40: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
                                       ^
vector2.cpp:5:25: error: expected '('
    Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
                        ^
vector2.cpp:5:39: error: expected ';' after expression
    Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
```

Am I using the wrong syntax to make the `Vector` class? Everything in it is pretty much identical to the book.

I've tried changing the syntax, but continue to get errors, and I'm not really sure what to change since I'm just starting with the language. Is this a problem with the book being C++11 and my compiler doesn't support that syntax?

Comment: _"Is this a problem with the book being C++11 and my compiler doesn't support that syntax?"_  This is valid C++11 code, but this code is not supported by earlier standards.  You are leaking memory though, with no `delete` to match your `new`.

Comment: You can pass `-std=c++11` to `g++` to get it to recognize C++11 things.

Comment: Or, do what the compiler is telling you - use parenthesis instead of braces: `Vector(int s) : elem(new double[s]), sz(s) {}` (which will still work in modern compilers)

Comment: What version of GCC do you have? Where did you get it from? Can you upgrade?

Comment: @DrewDormann The memory leak isn't an issue in this context, as the OS will just reclaim it when the program ends anyway.

Comment: @goatmilkshake you most likely want to upgrade your compiler if possible and not switch to writing code for compilers written before 2011. You may get this to build but it will hurt you in the long run by sticking to the 2003 or 1998 standard. You did not mention how you installed your compiler. If you installed MinGW you should uninstall it and switch to use msys2 to install the latest MinGW with gcc-12.X

Comment: @fireshadow52 _"the OS will just reclaim it when the program ends anyway"_ — even though in this trivial program the memory leak does not cause any further problems, it is still a memory leak, and as such I would say it is still a problem with the class' design. Beginners should learn early on to apply the [RAII idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) when designing classes that manage resources. Also, every C++ programmer should be aware of the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @heapunderrun No objections there. It's much better to instill good programming habits early on rather than trying to correct bad ones later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using Apple Clang Version 14.0.3 and I installed it with Xcode developer tools I believe

Comment: @heapunderrun thank you for the links, I'll try and fix the memory link with `delete`. And yeah, I'm just getting started I agree I want to make good habits now

Comment: IIRC Aples's Clang compiler still defaults to the C++03. You must explicitly enable later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear.
Change the line `Vector(int s) : elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {` to `Vector(int s) : elem(new double[s]), sz(s) {`.

Or you can specify option `-std=c++11` to adopt c++11's new features.

Comment: Thanks for typing that out, it wasn't clear to me!